# PHP cut text after find ","

Tags: php

I want to cut text after find ","

> input text > 12223443,3532432
>
> I want > 12223443

**text length is no fixed

Comment: look for `substr()` & `strpos()` combine these 2 and you have it.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried? There are several PHP methods which will do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function :

```
<?php
$parts = explode(',', "12223443,3532432");
echo $parts[0];
```

Or as @JustOnUnderMillions said with [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) functions :

```
<?php
echo substr("12223443,3532432", 0, strpos("12223443,3532432", ','));
```

Or even with [strstr](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strstr.php) and PHP 5.3+ (@sidyll and @JustOnUnderMillions) :

```
<?php
echo strstr("12223443,3532432", ',', true);
```

Comment: Just updated my answer to let him choose between all solutions ;-)

Comment: The *actual* reason you were downvoted originally is two-fold. First, the question is overly broad and the OP showed no effort in solving the problem. Second, there is a duplicate question which we should all search for first.